# Работа с несколькими таблицами c ORM Room

Tags: android, база-данных, android-room, room

Начал работать с Android Studio недавно. Вопрос по работе с Room. 
Есть четыре таблицы. Ниже код этих таблиц.

```
@Entity(tableName = "countries")
public class Countries {

   @NonNull
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   long id;
   String name;
   //get set constructor
}

@Entity(tableName = "produsers")
public class Produsers {

   @NonNull
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   long id;
   String name;
   //get set constructor
}

@Entity(tableName = "productsGroup")
public class ProductsGroup {

   @NonNull
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   long id;
   String name;
   //get set constructor
}

@Entity(tableName = "products",

       foreignKeys = {
               @ForeignKey(entity = Produsers.class,
                       parentColumns = "id",
                       childColumns = "idProduser"),
               @ForeignKey(entity = Countries.class,
                       parentColumns = "id",
                       childColumns = "idCountry"),
               @ForeignKey(entity = ProductsGroup.class,
                       parentColumns = "id",
                       childColumns = "idProductGroup"),

       },
       indices = @Index(value = {"name", "barcode", "seria"}
       )
)

public class Products {
   @NonNull
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   long id;

   @NonNull
   long idProduser;
   @NonNull
   long idCountry;
   @NonNull
   long idProductGroup;
   String name;
   String barcode;
   String seria;

}
```

Мне требуется выводить данные с таблицы Products и чтоб данные со связанных таблиц подхватывались. Как это написать и есть ли более развернутые примеры?Потому что все, что нашел в сети, без подробных примеров.

UPD.

Решил все на трех таблицах тестировать.
Нашел пример, где можно создать объект с полями, которые хочешь получить. 
Описал класс.

```
@Entity
public class Production {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name ="productId")
    int idProduct;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="produserName")
    String nameProduser;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="countryName")
    String nameCountry;

}
```

Написал запрос на получение данных.

```
@Dao
public interface DAOProduction {

    @Query("Select products.id as productId, producers.name as produserName, countries.name as countryName " +
            " From products ,producers, countries " +
            "Where products.idProducer == producers.id and products.idCountry == countries.id ")
    List<Production> getProduction();
}
```

Дописал getter методы, но возникает ошибка для всех полей

```
error: cannot find symbol variable getIdProduct
```

UPD.

Не разобрался почему нельзя создать getterы для получения полей объекта. 
При обращении на прямую к переменной получаю данные. 
Был бы признателен, если бы кто-то объяснил почему так это происходит.

```
 List<Production> productionList = daoProduction.getProduction();
        for (Production production : productionList) {
            if (production!=null)
            {
                Log.d("Log", production.idProduct + "-"+ production.nameCountry);
            }
        }
```

Comment: в room вы пишите обычные sql запросы на извлечение данных (синтаксис и возможности соответствуют SQLite, надстройкой над которой room и является) . Если у вас сложности с составлением sql-запросов, то лучшим решением будет почитать соответствующую литературу по СУБД, так как тема очень обширная и в формат ответа данного ресурса не вписывается.Так же вы можете дополнить вопрос и указать **конкретные** примеры, что именно вы хотите получить в запросе, тогда вполне вероятно кто-нибудь здесь поможет вам их составить

Comment: Что качается написания sql-запросов не является трудной задачей.

Comment: если вас интересует организация связей таблиц, как один ко многим, многие ко многим, то здесь [есть информация](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/534-urok-10-room-zapros-iz-neskolkih-tablic-relation.html), так же в этом курсе много другой полезной информации и по Room и по остальным компонентам Architecture Components

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. Сейчас смотрю как раз эту ссылку. Правда немного по-другому пришлось написать. Так как возникали ошибки из-за того, что объект не был определен как @Entity и не было первичного ключа.

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 способа. Можно с помощью аннотаций заставить либу подгружать данные из разных таблиц в одну модель, а можно делать это вручную. Мне лично ближе второй способ, т.к. он даёт полный контроль над происходящим и не завязан на конкретную реализацию связывания данных библиотекой.

**Способ связи данных в одну модель вручную**

1. Создайте нужные поля в моделях, пометив их `@Ignore` аннотацией:

   ```
   public class Parent {
       ...

       @Nullable
       @Ignore
       public List<Child> children;
   }
   ```

   ```
   public class Child{
       ...


       public long parentId;
   }
   ```
2. В `Dao` классе создайте метод для получения и Parent и добавления в него Child

   ```
   @Dao
   public abstract class MyDao {
       @Query("SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE id = :id")
       public abstract Parent getParentById(long id);

       @Query("SELECT * FROM ChildWHERE parentId = :parentId")
       public abstract List<Child> getChildrenByParentId(long parentId);

       public Parent getParentByIdWithChilds(long id) {
           Parent parent = getParentById(id);
           List<Child> children = getChildrenByParentId(id);
           parent.children = children;
           return parent;
       }
   }
   ```

**Способ связи данных в одну модель автоматически**

1. Создайте модель для Parent и Child

   ```
   public class ParentWithChildren {
       @Embedded
       public Parent parent;
       @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entity = Child.class, entityColumn = "parentId")
       public List<Child> children;
   }
   ```
2. Создайте Dao

   ```
   @Dao
   public interface MyDao {
       @Transaction 
       @Query("SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE id = :id")
       public ParentWithChildren getParentById(long id);
   }
   ```

Способ взят из этой статьи: [Room: Один ко многим](https://habr.com/ru/post/349280/). Там же приведены некоторые подводные камни и ограничения.